# Can we use multiple typescript files without a module loader?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my intention
Add two typescript files say: 1- app.ts and 2- decorator.ts, app.ts uses a class defined in decorator.ts.

I am trying to create a simple sample without the use of module loader so I thought in my HTML I'd add the scripts.js file references in correct order but it will work, but no I got ReferenceError: exports is not defined

My project is a ASP.NET Core Web application with static files only. I have hosted the [full code on github here](https://github.com/fahadash/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/src/MultipleFiles).

I am thinking it would work fine if I use a module loader, is this true? Can I not use these two scripts without a module loader and simple includes?

Comment: You could try setting `--module` to `none`, or try `--outFile`. But really, I would just use [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) which can bundle up your code without any configuration at all.

Comment: @Aaron thanks. My intention is to not use any module loader or web pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the two JavaScript files with individual `<script>` tags and have them be able to access each other's definitions, you'll need to make them not modules by removing the imports and exports.  Then `Decorator` will be defined globally and the second JavaScript file can access it by that name without importing.  Furthermore, `app` will be defined globally so that your `onload` handler can call it.  If you don't want to define a huge number of globals, consider using a `namespace`, which will effectively group all your definitions under a single global name.